# CakePHP returning 502 when passing large dataset to the view

Tags: cakephp

I am passing a large data set to a view (~3000 rows). The view then presents the data in a table.

This works locally, but returns a 502 in the server.

I am not using pagination for this particular query because the client wants the whole list in one go. Retrieving the results is actually working fine, I can stop the process and view the query results.

The issue comes from passing the large array to the view using set(): `$this->set('data', $data);`

If I comment this line, the process completes as expected (with no data to display obviously).
I tried saving the array in the session, and using this to render the table on the view. This works, but it crashes the Cake debugging plugin.

I also tried caching the data, and retrieving the data from the cache on the view. This also works.

What could cause the $this->set() to return a 502? Is there a setting I am missing to allow passing large dataset to the view?

Also, there is nothing relevant in the logs.

Thanks,

Comment: What, specifically, is `$data`? Is it an array with 3000 rows in it? Or a query object that will return 3000 rows when you iterate over it?

Comment: `$data` is an array with 3000 rows. Running the query, iterating over the results is fine. It takes 3-4 seconds.

I can even print the array at this stage with print_r() and exit at this stage the view the data.

I also tried to remove all the HTML table logic from the template, and just print a Hello World message, but it doesn't get to that.

Comment: Have you tried passing the query that generates those rows to the view instead of the rows themselves? Seems like maybe you're hitting some memory limit or the like by pulling all of that data into memory at once and then making a copy of it.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I didn't try that. I was able to allocate more memory which works for now. I'll try this when I have a chance. Thanks,